# Is downloading lecture notes legal?

Tags: united-states, copyright, fair-use

It's really tiresome to ask each professor to use his slides for educational purposes as I have done [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6IdqsEZAsS2OUp6dXdKMGFVMDA).

If a rights owner publishes a work online in a way that it is publicly accessible, but does not give a specific license (e.g. does not say 'you can download this for personal use'), is it legal to download (i.e. copy) that work for personal use, although there is no explicit license?*

*-Post updation given by @Brandin

Comment: I wonder about the effect of putting one's writings on the web without a copyright notice. For an author to _publish_ (i.e. distribute to the public) without a copyright notice can result in forfeiture of the copyright. _Public display_ is one of the exclusive rights of copyright owners under the 1976 copyright law. At that time the web did not exist, but I would guess putting things on the web would be considered public display.

Comment: Works are copyrighted with or without copyright notice. It is very, very, very hard to lose copyright of a work. "Public display" most definitely doesn't mean loss of copyright.

Comment: "It's really tiresome to ask each professor to use his slides" - are you asking to copy them and include them in your own publication, or just to view them? Your question 1. implies that you just want to click and view them. If it is on a public web site and it is clickable then I'm not sure the act that you clicked it counts as making a copy, or at least not an infringing copy.

Comment: @Brandin:I'm just asking to use these slides or documents for educational or personal use.I'm not looking to copy it into any journal or publication but just for studying.

Comment: @justin So you just want permission to click on the download link and choose "Save As..." to save it on your computer?

Comment: @Brandin:I would just like to knoow whether it's _legal_ to download documents available on the internet for educational or personal use.

Comment: @justin Maybe a way to clarify the question would be: if a rights owner publishes a work online in a way that it is publicly accessible, but does not give a specific license (e.g. does not say 'you can download this for personal use'), is it legal to download (i.e. copy) that work for personal use, although there is no explicit license? Be sure to say what you mean by personal use, and whether you intend to redistribute it or not.

Comment: @Brandin:Yeah absolutely.I would update the question right know.